# removing milliseconds from a oracle tmstmp field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a TIMESTAMP(6) field in Oracle and I need to remove the millisecond component from the time.

For example I have

```
10/20/2014 10:34:06.356000 AM
```

and I would like to remove the milliseconds so that I have

```
10/20/2014 10:34:06 AM
```

Do you know the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
select cast(col as timestamp(0))
```

EDIT:

The easiest way to avoid rounding is to use `trunc()` or to subtract half a second:

```
select cast(col - 0.5/(24*60*60) as timestamp(0))
```

Comment: this works but it does rounding. Is there a way to make it not round and just remove the milliseconds without rounding up or down?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
FROM DUAL;
```

if you need 12-hour date format

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "NOW"
FROM DUAL;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05f84/19)

Comment: this works but I need the filed to be a timestamp(0).  when I run your code I lose the AM/PM and the time loses its GMT format. Can it be cast to a timestamp(0)? then it might work

Comment: if you need 12 hrs format with AM/PM then use the second query

Comment: but this is still a CHAR. I need it timestamp(0).  is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can either cast it to a timestamp with no fractional seconds (this will round to the nearest second):

```
CAST( your_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP(0) )
```

Or to a `DATE` data type (this will truncate to the nearest second):

```
CAST( your_timestamp AS DATE )
```

If you want it as a `TIMESTAMP(0)` data type then cast it back:

```
CAST( CAST( your_timestamp AS DATE ) AS TIMESTAMP(0) )
```

Or you can convert it to a formatted string and specify the format model you want to use (this will truncate to the nearest second):

```
TO_CHAR( your_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7db4ac/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_timestamp ) AS
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-10-25 12:53:12.10076' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CAST( your_timestamp AS TIMESTAMP(0) ) AS "Timestamp",
       CAST( your_timestamp AS DATE ) AS "Date",
       TO_CHAR( your_timestamp, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) AS "String"
FROM   your_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7db4ac/2/0)**:

```
|             Timestamp |                 Date |              String |
|-----------------------|----------------------|---------------------|
| 2017-10-25 12:53:12.0 | 2017-10-25T12:53:12Z | 25-10-2017 12:53:12 |
```

note: How the `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` are formatted in the output will depend on your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` and `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameters but you can directly control the formatting of `TO_CHAR` when you specify a format model.

Answer (score -2):

This might help!

```
select substr(to_char('10/20/2014 10:34:06.356000 AM'),1,instr(to_char('10/20/2014 10:34:06.356000 AM'),'.')-1)||' '||
substr(to_char('10/20/2014 10:34:06.356000 AM'),-2,instr(to_char('10/20/2014 10:34:06.356000 AM'),'.')-1) "Date"
from dual;
```